# No value provided for input HTTP label: Key

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to send a file to s3, `@aws-sdk/client-s3` I think i got everything correct but when sending I keep getting the error `No value provided for input HTTP label: Key`

here is my console.log of the `buckeparam`

```js
// result of console.log
the bucket {
  Bucket: 'image-camlist',
  Body: Blob { size: 187759, type: 'image/jpeg' },
  key: 'bfbfr.jpg'
}
Error Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: Key.
```

it got the key `bfbfr.jpg` already, how come it's still complaining about the key ?

Comment: Maybe the API is case sensitive, try `Key`

Comment: Can you share the code for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: ah sheet, the key property must capitalized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require(‘@aws-sdk/client-s3’);
const params = {
    Bucket: "image-camlist",
    Key: 'bfbfr.txt', // Pay attention to the casing of Key property
    Body: 'hello world',
};

client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using a env variable for "Bucket" property.
I got the same error message, as described in the question.
It turned out I had a **typo in the env variable** name.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: "test.txt",
    Body: "some content",
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it was throwing error as I wrote key with small **K** instead it should be written with **capital K**

Comment: Thank you for you contribution @Usama, but this is the same answer as the well crafted and accepted solution above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597743/3528232